# Ocultar y volver a mostrar las capas de un PDF en el panel de Acrobat

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, itextsharp

Estoy usando iTextSharp 5.5.10.0.

Tengo un PDF con varias capas resultado de haber unido varios ficheros. Cuando lo abro con Acrobat Reader aparecen las capas y los nombres originales de los ficheros que uní.

**Primer problema:**
Si uso este código una vez, en el panel de Acrobat desaparecen las capas y se quedan los nombres de los ficheros unidos:

```
Public Shared Sub OcultarLayers(ByVal source As String, ByVal destination As String)
    Using reader = New PdfReader(source)
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations()
        reader.RemoveUnusedObjects()
        Using stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(reader, New FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            Dim capas = From cada In stamper.GetPdfLayers
            For Each capa In capas
                capa.Value.OnPanel = False
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Tengo que usarlo dos veces para que no aparezcan los nombres de los ficheros:

```
Public Shared Sub OcultarLayers(ByVal source As String, ByVal destination As String)
 Using memo As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    Using readerMemo = New PdfReader(source)
        readerMemo.ConsolidateNamedDestinations()
        readerMemo.RemoveUnusedObjects()
        Using stamperMemo As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(readerMemo, memo)
            stamperMemo.Writer.CloseStream = False
            Dim capas = From cada In stamperMemo.GetPdfLayers
            For Each capa In capas
                capa.Value.OnPanel = False
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
    memo.Position = 0
    Using reader = New PdfReader(memo)
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations()
        reader.RemoveUnusedObjects()
        Using stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(reader, New FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            Dim capas = From cada In stamper.GetPdfLayers
            For Each capa In capas
                capa.Value.OnPanel = False
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

**Segundo Problema:**

No funciona poner de nuevo `capa.Value.OnPanel = True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución al primer problema**

La solución a la chapuza de modificar dos veces el mismo fichero es esta:

```
    Using reader = New PdfReader(source)
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations()
        reader.RemoveUnusedObjects()
        Using stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(reader, New FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            Dim capas = From cada In stamper.GetPdfLayers
            For Each capa In capas
                Dim padre As PdfLayer = capa.Value
                Do While Not IsNothing(padre.Parent)
                    padre = padre.Parent
                Loop
                padre.OnPanel = False
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
```

No se puede cambiar la propiedad de las capas children sin cambiar antes la parent:

> public void setOnPanel(boolean onPanel)
>
> Sets the visibility of the layer in Acrobat's layer panel.       If
>   false the layer cannot be directly manipulated by the user. Note that
>   any children layers will also be absent from the panel.

Al segundo problema no he encontrado solución.

He probado cambiar las parent y children y no funciona.